# How do you calculate fees with bitcoind?

Tags: bitcoind

Here is the transaction id as an example, please help me calculate using bitcoind: 10ff046cb00483c4b4222fe3d1798b98d5a17af55ff7fc0a6e1e2398b86c13bd

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calculation of transaction fee for transaction](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/60490/calculation-of-transaction-fee-for-transaction)

Comment: My question specifically pertains to using bitcoind, the other question is a little more broad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Fees are the difference between the total inputs and the total outputs.**

**To retrieve the total out:** Let’s make a `getrawtransaction` request with this transaction id, and add all the "vout" values together to get the total.

The request will look like this (use "1" at the end to return JSON):

> bitcoin-cli getrawtransaction
>   10ff046cb00483c4b4222fe3d1798b98d5a17af55ff7fc0a6e1e2398b86c13bd 1

In this example there is only 1 output:

```
  "vout": [
    {
      "value": 3.60555045,
      "n": 0,
      "scriptPubKey": {
        "asm": "OP_DUP OP_HASH160 ccc497f13cf4c598201e4b12353649be44172b01 OP_EQUALVERIFY OP_CHECKSIG",
        "hex": "76a914ccc497f13cf4c598201e4b12353649be44172b0188ac",
        "reqSigs": 1,
        "type": "pubkeyhash",
        "addresses": [
          "1KfiMh5SDTYBGrDDHfSegrHkkWZQ2mSXtP"
        ]
      }
    }   ], ...
```

**To retrieve the total input:** We need make an additional request for each input to get the input values. So in this example there is one input:

```
  "vin": [
    {
      "txid": "b13b4765e46228f3239858c9f18e766b72bed24a56c52b9692e7f021c376e7ce",
      "vout": 1,
      "scriptSig": {
        "asm": "3044022044ca9b69f8c14eccd400be62a5320c8938aee176033c91f4cb17f57b14a20de402206e520a6398b01467772395557415bde2b7879e0e554eb6306718aa81fae5247d[ALL] 0373b9e8c6bd75e3029c00d629baff141895a4444d55894d48f0426842608d8e4d",
        "hex": "473044022044ca9b69f8c14eccd400be62a5320c8938aee176033c91f4cb17f57b14a20de402206e520a6398b01467772395557415bde2b7879e0e554eb6306718aa81fae5247d01210373b9e8c6bd75e3029c00d629baff141895a4444d55894d48f0426842608d8e4d"
      },
      "sequence": 4294967295
    }
  ],
...
```

We are interested in the "txid" and "vout". We need to make an additional getrawtransaction request for this id, and look at the value of the 2nd ouput (since vout is 1). That output is here:

```
{
  "value": 3.61007045,
  "n": 1,
  "scriptPubKey": {
    "asm": "OP_DUP OP_HASH160 02952d768c840f30a49e20af5bd4219210a14d24 OP_EQUALVERIFY OP_CHECKSIG",
    "hex": "76a91402952d768c840f30a49e20af5bd4219210a14d2488ac",
    "reqSigs": 1,
    "type": "pubkeyhash",
    "addresses": [
      "1Ef4RcUBZfrFyoVxZeU7tH5dRd9SXcJHN"
    ]
  }
}
```

Now we can subtract the total inputs from the total outputs to get the fees: 3.61007045 - 3.60555045 = 0.00452 in fees